# How to update embedded document in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I've looked through the mongoose API, and many questions on SO and on the google group, and still can't figure out updating embedded documents.

I'm trying to update this particular userListings object with the contents of args.

```
for (var i = 0; i < req.user.userListings.length; i++) {
    if (req.user.userListings[i].listingId == req.params.listingId) {
        User.update({
            _id: req.user._id,
            'userListings._id': req.user.userListings[i]._id
        }, {
            'userListings.isRead': args.isRead,
            'userListings.isFavorite': args.isFavorite,
            'userListings.isArchived': args.isArchived
        }, function(err, user) {
            res.send(user);
        });
    }
}
```

Here are the schemas:

```
var userListingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    listingId: ObjectId,
    isRead: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    isFavorite: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    isArchived: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userListings: [userListingSchema]
});
```

This find also doesn't work, which is probably the first issue:

```
User.find({
    '_id': req.user._id,
    'userListings._id': req.user.userListings[i]._id
}, function(err, user) {
    console.log(err ? err : user);
});
```

which returns:

```
{ stack: [Getter/Setter],
  arguments: [ 'path', undefined ],
  type: 'non_object_property_call',
  message: [Getter/Setter] }
```

That should be the equivalent of this mongo client call:

```
db.users.find({'userListings._id': ObjectId("4e44850101fde3a3f3000002"), _id: ObjectId("4e4483912bb87f8ef2000212")})
```

Running:

```
mongoose v1.8.1
mongoose-auth v0.0.11
node v0.4.10
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

when you already have the user, you can just do something like this:

```
var listing = req.user.userListings.id(req.params.listingId);

listing.isRead = args.isRead;
listing.isFavorite = args.isFavorite;
listing.isArchived = args.isArchived;

req.user.save(function (err) {
  // ...
});
```

as found here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

> **Finding a sub-document**
>
> Each document has an _id. DocumentArrays have a special id method for looking up a document by its _id.
>
> ```
> var doc = parent.children.id(id);
> ```

*** * warning * ***

as @zach pointed out, you have to declare the sub-document's schema before the actual document 's schema to be able to use the `id()` method.

Comment: I'm getting "TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] has no method 'id'"

Comment: Is that a mongoose-auth issue? That's where req.user is assigned.

Comment: the mongoose docu says: "DocumentArrays have an special method id that filters your embedded documents by their _id property (each embedded document gets one)". but i haven't tried this myself.

Comment: I get the same issue as FrederickCook. Any answer on why this happens? I checked the DocumentsArray and id is undefined.

Comment: I was struggling with this as well. It turns out that the order in which you define your schemas matters. If the sub-doc isn't first, that .id ends up being undefined. More here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/622

Answer (score 0):

Is this just a mismatch on variables names?

You have `user.userListings[i].listingId` in the `for` loop but `user.userListings[i]._id` in the `find`.

Are you looking for `listingId` or `_id`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the parent object, and markModified the nested document.

That´s the way we do it

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
  Profile.findById(req.params.id, function (err, profile) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!profile) { return res.send(404); }
    var updated = _.merge(profile, req.body);
    updated.markModified('NestedObj');
    updated.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.json(200, profile);
    });
  });
};
```