# Mongoose.js: How can I update a deep embedded document by its id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How can I update an embedded document that is more than one level deep by using the `_id` of the item I wish to update?

For example, if I have the following in my model file:

```
var Subitems = new Schema({
  "title": String,
  "body": String
)}

var Items = new Schema({
  "title": String,
  "subitems": [Subitems]
)};

var Projects = new Schema({
  "title": String,
  "description": String,
  "items": [Items]
});

var exports = module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', Projects);
```

How would I go about updating the `body` of one of my `subitems` where I know the `_id` of the `subitems` element?

I assume I would first find the Project (easy enough), and then push to the `subitems` and save the Project. So the question is, how do you push to a more than one level deep embed without having to iterate through everything above it? Can I do it by its `_id` ?

Comment: This question answer to mine! Thanks! :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I just figured it out. Funny how that always happens right after posting to SO :)

Here's what I did, let me know if there's any better/different way:

```
var myitem  = req.project.items.id(item_id);
myitem.body = req.body.item.body;

req.project.save(function (err){
  //woohoo! updated the embedded doc with the new values!      
});
```

I figured it out by following the advice in the selected answer in this SO post:
[How to update embedded document in mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035092/how-to-update-embedded-document-in-mongoose)