# Updating embedded document Mongoose - existing instance save/update etc

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't seem to be able to update/add an array of embedded documents to a parent document for the life of me.

Please excuse the lengthy script, but it just wasn't going to help me or be possible to assist if I didn't include all of the code. Feel free to offer any other Node advice.

I have tried hundreds of variations and have looked in all possible resources to get this to work, or do something similar, but have been unsuccessful for a few hours now.  I would greatly appreciate any help getting this working.  Please let me know if there's something I missed.

This answer: [How to update embedded document in mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035092/how-to-update-embedded-document-in-mongoose) was the closest to helping me (because I already had the company/instance) but alas, I've yet to get it working.

Thanks for any help!

```
Node --version v0.10.21        
mongodb@1.3.19
    │ ├── bson@0.2.2
    │ └── kerberos@0.0.3
    ├── mongoose@3.6.20


    var http = require('http');
    var db = require('../config/db') //Connects to DB successfully
    var async = require('async');
    var request = require('request');
    var download = require('./download');
    request = require('request');
    var cheerio = require('cheerio');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        Schema = mongoose.Schema,
        ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

    var filingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        dateFiled: String,
        formName: String,
        XBRLREF: String,
        filingHREF: String,
        title: String,
        type: String
    });

    Filing = mongoose.model('Filing', filingSchema);

    var companySchema = mongoose.Schema({
        symbol: String,
        name: String,
        secURL: String,
        mc: String,
        filings: [filingSchema],
        irLink: String
    });

    Company = mongoose.model('Company', companySchema);

    function getCompanies(callback) {
        Company.find({
            cik: {
                $ne: ""
            }
        }, function(err, companies) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("error getting companies " + err)
            }
            // console.log(companies.length);
            callback(null, companies);
        })
    };

    function createURLs(companies, callback) {
        // create a URL for querying the SEC website for the main, first company page with 100 filings of type 10 only
        companies.forEach(function(company) {
            if (company.symbol) {
                // console.log("company.nasdaqSymbol is: " + company.nasdaqSymbol);
                // create url to download
                cik = company.cik
                // If you try to run this code you can use 'AMZN' in place of the cik below (most other symbols too)
                company.link = 'http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=' + cik + '&type=10&owner=exclude&count=100&output=xml'
            }
        });
        callback(null, companies);
    }

    function downloadSEC(companies, callback) {
        // iterate through each URL and query the SEC website - get the results and return page as data
        companies.forEach(function(company) {
            download(company.link, function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    // Call separate function that will grab the elements we want from SEC meta-page
                    // Example data/response page: view-source:http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=AMZN&type=&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=100&output=xml
                    getLinks(data, company);
                }
            });
        });
    };

    function getLinks(data, company) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(data);
        var filings = [];
        $('filing').each(function() {
            // Have tried many versions of the below including var filing = new Filing etc....  also company.filings.push(filing) (throws: type cast error)
            // Example data: view-source:http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=AMZN&type=&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=100&output=xml
            var filing = {
                dateFiled: $(this).find("dateFiled").text(),
                xbrlRef: $(this).find('XBRLREF').text(),
                formName: $(this).find('formName').text(),
                type: $(this).find('type').text(),
                filingHREF: $(this).find('filingHREF').text()
            };
            filings.push(filing);
        });
        update(company, filings);
    }

    function update(company, filings) {
        console.log('company_id is: ' + company._id);
        // Have tried seemingly thousands of combinations of C[c]ompany.save/update etc. below
        company.save({
            _id: company._id
        }, {
            filings: filings
        }, function(err, company) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("error updating filings: " + err);
            }
            console.log('company is: ' + company);
        });
    }

    async.waterfall([getCompanies, createURLs, downloadSEC, getLinks]);
```

Comment: Note: the problem is only with the model.save/update part at the bottom.

Comment: I have successfully achieved the solution for the same kinda problem. Can you tell me where are you facing the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem is with instantiating the Filing, if I need to, and adding it to the parent company.  So how to pass the filing to Mongoose, essentially.

Comment: I thought that something like:    `company.filings.push(filings)`   then `Company.update(_id: company.id, company, function(err, company){...` would have worked but throws a CastError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have hacked together the parts of your code that weren't included (db and download), and I think I have everything working.

I am using mongoose 3.8 and node 0.10, but I think it should still work for you.
You could do several things here, but this issues a [mongodb findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/)

```
function update(company, filings) {
    console.log('company_id is: ' + company._id);

    Company.findByIdAndUpdate(company._id, {
        filings: filings
    }, function(err, company) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error updating filings: " + err);
        }
        console.log('company is: ' + company);
    });
}
```

I also noticed that async.waterfall doesn't need the getLinks function since you aren't using the callback.

Comment: Thanks Jwags.  I got another way working - using save as well.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.  I also had some import error as well which I believe hampered my success with this.