# Update embedded document mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm looking for an easy way of updating an embedded document using mongoose without having to set each specific field manually. Looking at the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035092/how-to-update-embedded-document-in-mongoose), once you find the embedded document that you want to update you have to actually set each respective property and then save the parent. What I would prefer to do is pass in an update object and let MongoDB set the updates.

e.g. if I was updating a regular (non embedded) document I would do this:

```
models.User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.userId}, req.body.user, function(err, user) {
    err ? resp.status(500).send(err) : user ? resp.send(user) : resp.status(404).send();
});
```

Here I don't actually have to go through each property in req.body.user and set the changes. I can't find a way of doing this kind of thing with sub documents as well ?

My Schema is as follows:

```
var UserSchema = BaseUserSchema.extend({ 
    isActivated: { type: Boolean, required: true },
    files: [FileSchema]
});

var FileSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    size: { type: Number, required: true },
    type: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

And I'm trying to update a file based on user and file id.

Do I need to create a helper function to set the values, or is there a MongoDB way of doing this ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well presuming that you have something that has you "filedata" in a variable, and of course the user _id that you are updating, then you wan't the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) operator:

```
var user = { /* The user information, at least the _id */
var filedata = { /* From somewhere with _id, name, size, type */ };

models.User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": user._id, "files._id": filedata._id },
    {
        "$set": {
            "name": filedata.name,
            "size": filedata.size,
            "type": filedata.type
        }
    },
    function(err,user) {
      // Whatever in here such a message, but the update is already done.
    }
);
```

Or really, just only [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) the fields that you actually mean to "update" as long as you know which ones you mean. So if you only need to change the "size" then just set that for example.

Comment: Hey Neil. Thanks for the answer. I think maybe I wasn't clear in my question. I understand that I can set each value individually within the update. But what I would like to do is just pass in an object that contains the updates I would like to make to the embedded file document. This would be useful when making a HTTP put request for example, where I don't know what updates the user would like to make. Is this possible in mongoose/mongodb without writing a helper function to set the properties before saving ? Thanks again.

Comment: @Sherlock you're right, your question is not very clear and neither is that comment. Perhaps you should update your question with a clear demonstration of what exactly you want to do. But unless you are using a **`$set`** or **`$push`** type of syntax within the update portion you cannot do anything other than replace the whole array.

Comment: Ok that answers my question. Thanks.